# Django - How to move file between models with different storages?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-storage

I have a model "Local" that uses the django `default_storage` and contains the `FileField` for a locally stored file:

```
class Local(Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=..., storage=LOCAL_STORAGE)
```

I have another model that uses a different storage class, for remote storage, equally with a `FileField`.

```
class Remote(Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=..., storage=REMOTE_STORAGE)
```

When processing of a file locally is complete, I want to be able to move it from the Local Storage to the Remote storage.

I don't want to have to read the local file, and then create a new one in the remote model as this can take too much time.

Is there any way to move across storages, or even reference the file in the Remote model and when save is called have it saved into the new REMOTE_STORAGE from the LOCAL_STORAGE.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to duplicate a file across storages without making an intermediate copy. Something like this will migrate all records from `Local` to `Remote` by buffering each file as a `TemporaryFile` and then wrapping it with a django `File`:

```py
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
from django.core.files import File

for row in Local.objects.all():
    with TemporaryFile() as temp:
        temp.write(row.file.read())
        Remote.objects.create(file=File(temp), ...)
```